# How to turn laptop display ON and OFF with a certain key?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to turn on and off my laptop screen easily (without it going to sleep or hibernate mode). I have various automation scripts running in the background (which include mouse movement and certain keystrokes), and sometimes I even access my laptop remotely. It's a Windows 10 machine.

I am searching for a way to turn off the display on my laptop (without closing the lid). I tried to set it by using various options available in Windows, but whenever there is a mouse movement, or if I press a key via remote desktop, my laptop's screen turns back on.

I would like it to remain turned off until I press a pre-determined key. For example, I would like to set a hotkey "Ctrl + alt + o", which would turn off my laptop screen. In case there is a mouse movement or key pressed, I would like it to remain off. I would like it to turn back on only when I press "Ctrl + alt + o" again.

I spent a lot of time on a research and tried various solutions, but usually none of them work. Powershell scripts work fine if I need to turn off the screen, but it turns back on as soon as I move the mouse.

Some of the solutions included setting up screen brightness to 0 so it looks like it's turned off, but unfortunately that didn't work for me either. Even if the brightness is set to 0, my screen is still fully visible.

This is very strange since the solution on my old PC which had a monitor would be to simply turn off the monitor by pressing the power button. Is it possible that there is no option to do something like that if you are using laptop?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The Power Button is not any key. Just set the monitor to turn off after x minutes of inactivity.  You can also use Nirsoft.  .....  nircmd" monitor off   .... Not all monitors support Nirsoft.    With either method, the monitor turns on with a mouse move or keypress.

Comment: Some laptops have a key to turn off/on the screen. Checkout this image https://redhat.discourse-cdn.com/fedoraproject/original/3X/c/0/c0e572e9bc07f932dd7f1bfb704d788a108b1992.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Use the free [nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

You may create two `.bat` files on the desktop and assign them shortcut
keys. You would use the following commands:

```
\path\nircmd.exe monitor off

\path\nircmd.exe monitor on
```

Comment: +1 but, he did say with a key, so AutoHotKey with nircmd would work.  I think MS PowerTools added the ability to launch programs with keys though... not near a windows pc at the moment to check.

Comment: Remember that nicrmd does not work on all monitors. Tru for monitors here.

Answer (score 0):

The power button is not any key, and I do not know of a key that will turn the monitor off. In general, it is very unlikely you could do this.

Also, monitors on various laptops are different.

So I use two methods, depending on the monitor:

**(1) For All laptop monitors:**

All laptop monitors (that I have used) support turning the display off after x minutes. I use this and it works well. Any mouse move or keypress will turn on the monitor.

**(2) For some laptop monitors:**

Some monitors (but not all) support Nirsoft.  Download nircmd from Nirsoft and put it somewhere logical.  Then make a batch file with nircmd monitor off.  Any mouse move or keypress will turn on the monitor so I do not need monitor on.

Put the batch file with the monitor off string on the desktop and it is a simple double click (instead of one key).

Comment: I need a way so that mouse or any key press using the remote software like Parsec doesn't turn on the monitor

Comment: You were not clear. If the monitor goes black by timing out or someone using monitor off, then a keypress will turn it back on. Not much you can do about that. If you do not want the monitor on for remote access, then you need to turn it off. I have used all these methods including remote access.